# Error in configuring Spring project with Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am getting the below errors in my spring mvc project.

1. Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource

2. Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager

3. Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean

4. Build path is incomplete. Cannot find class file for org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

required dependencies has been added but not sure where I am going wrong.

Below are the pom.xml and jpaContext.xml.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
                <map>
                    <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
                    <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
                </map>
            </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
          <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
          <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fitnesstracker?autoReconnect=true" />
          <property name="username" value="root" />
          <property name="password" value="root" />
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Your dependencies are missing.Add <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

Comment: The pom.xml i posted earlier was of a different project by mistake. I have corrected and posted the correct pom.xml and it contains spring-jdbc dependency but getting the same error.

Comment: Why are you mixing up versions, although this may not be the cause of your problem

Comment: Thats the issue here..check my answer hope it helps

Comment: Then as @Akshay suggested, change your pom, to remove version conflicts and mismatches, try again. This seems like an ugly `pom.xml`

Comment: yes I have changed the versions for all the spring dependencies and used the latest version for hibernate-entitymanager dependency and now I am not getting any error.

Comment: Accept answer if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 `org.springframework` dependencies 2 of version `3.2.6.RELEASE` and other 2 of version `3.2.0.RELEASE`. Kindly have the same version of all spring dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Try to clean and give a try once. i think rest all dependencies are in place

Comment: The pom.xml which was posted earlier was incorrect, I have updated and posted the correct pom.xml which contains the spring-jdbc dependency. But still it is giving the same error.

Comment: Could you please change the version @Arindam in your pom.xml for <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>